# How to make vmware remote console to show scaled display?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vmware

I am using [VMRC](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMRC90&productId=491) 9.0 on my MacOS with an Ubuntu VM. 
But it does not occupy the full screen size available and always open in a small window.

If I maximize the window, the extra space on left and right is blacked out. 
Working with a reduced screen size is difficult, how can I force vmrc to scale to my screen size.

[image]